# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1) (thinkstats, install_test.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x

el siguiente programa es parte del libro thinkstats de Allen Downey:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import myplot
import Pmf

def NormalPdf(x):
   return math.exp(-x**2/2) / math.sqrt(2 * math.pi)
def Linspace(start, stop, n):
   return [start + (stop-start) * float(i)/(n-1) for i in range(n)]
def RenderPdf(mu, sigma, n=101):
   xs = Linspace(mu-4*sigma, mu+4*sigma, n)
   ys = [NormalPdf((x-mu) / sigma) for x in xs]
   return xs, ys

def main():
   xs, ys = RenderPdf(100, 15)

   n = 34
   pyplot.fill_between(xs[-n:], ys[-n:], y2=0.0001, color='blue', alpha=0.2)
   s = 'Congratulations!\nIf you got this far,\nyou must be here.'
   d = dict(shrink=0.05)
   pyplot.annotate(s, [127, 0.02], xytext=[80, 0.05], arrowprops=d)
   myplot.Plot(xs, ys,
               clf=False,
               show=True,
               title='Distribution of IQ',
               xlabel='IQ',
               ylabel='PDF',
               legend=False
              )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Después de compilar dicho programa, obtuve el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "install_test.py", line 49, in <module>
main()
File "install_test.py", line 45, in main
legend=False
File "/home/ubuntu/TS-I/myplot.py", line 174, in Plot
pyplot.plot(xs, ys, style, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 
2795, in plot
 is not None else {}), **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", 
line 1666, in plot
 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", 
line 225, in __call__
 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", 
line 405, in _plot_args
 seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", 
line 312, in _makeline
 seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 
404, in __init__
 self.update(kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 
974, in update
 ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 
974, in <listcomp>
 ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 
970, in _update_property.format(type(self).__name__, k))

AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'clf'
```

Después de haber leído algunos post de stackoverflow, pude solucionarlo parcialmente. Esto lo logre modificando una linea en otro programa en python llamado myplot.py; ese programa es demasiado largo, por lo que solo pondré las lineas conflictivas. En un inicio, el programa myplot.py estaba así:

```
options = Underride(options, linewidth=3, alpha=0.8)
pyplot.plot(xs, ys, style, **options)
```

Posteriormente, usando algunos post de aquí, lo modifique así:

```
options, = Underride(options, linewidth=3, alpha=0.8)
pyplot.plot(xs, ys, style, **options)
```

Y entonces al compilar install_test.py, ahora obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "install_test.py", line 49, in <module>
 main()
File "install_test.py", line 45, in main
 legend=False
File "/home/ubuntu/TS-I/myplot.py", line 173, in Plot
 options, = Underride(options, linewidth=3, alpha=0.8)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Leí algunos post del sitio, sin embargo ninguno se parece a mi programa, intente poner dos comas o dejar espacio pero sigue dando el mismo error. Por lo poco que he leído el error se debe a que falta un elemento en la lista al que le debo asignar un nuevo valor del lado izquierdo de la igualdad, espero y puedan ayudarme a solucionar mi problema. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Amahury ¿Puedes colocar la traza completa del error y no solo la última línea del mismo?

Comment: Hola, ahora los errores tienen la traza completa, gracias por tu interés.

Comment: Si no me equivoco (si es posible proporciona el código) `Underride` retorna un diccionario seguro, por lo que no puedes hacer `options, = Underride(options, linewidth=3, alpha=0.8)`, ya que retorna un solo objeto y con  `options, = ` intentas desempaquetar el diccionario, asociando a `options` la primera clave, pero si el diccionario tiene más de una clave el método falla porque solo tienes una variable. Eventualmente pudo solventar tu problema si `Underride` retorna un diccinario con una sola clave, pero no es correcto hacer esto.

Comment: El error es que se está pasando un argumento keyword, que viene en el diccionario `options` retornado por `Underrate` incorrecto. Es simple reproducir el error: `from matplotlib import pyplot; pyplot.plot([], [], clf=True)`. El argumento `clf`  no es válido para `plot`. ¿Tienes la seguridad de no estar ejecutando código desfazado? En los repos de A.Downey el único install_test.py que encuentro es https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkBayes2/blob/master/install_test.py

Comment: Existen dos versiones del libro think stats, el que yo estoy usando es la primera versión (con programas hechos en python2), el programa install_test.py que estoy ejecutando lo puedes encontrar aquí:  https://github.com/boboppie/downey-think_stats/blob/master/code/install_test.py; El programar myplot.py es demasiado largo, lo puedes revisar aquí:  http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/myplot.py; el IDE que utilizo usa python3, de ahí que he estado teniendo algunos problemas "de traducción", sin embargo he logrado que la mayoría de programas compilen haciendo algunas modificaciones.